# Adding or removing columns in result set of sql query depending on value of other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have a query that returns a result set of columns A and B from table First_Table. I want to limit the result set to those columns if the value of column X in table Second_Table is 0, and I want to add column C from table First_Table if the value of column X is 1.

The problem is easily resolved using a Python for example whereby I just have a variable as an empty string if value in column X is 0 or it would be equal to the string 'First_Table.ColumnC AS [Dynamic Value],', and I just format the sql in the script accordingly.

If Else solution is not an elegant way because I have multiple columns to add dynamically depending on multiple values...

I am just looking for some ideas on directions.. I have been looking at this for a while, might be bogged up

Comment: It is always a good idea to think about the consumer of your result. It is easier to deal with a known structure, where some columns remain empty as it is to deal with a set generically. In general it is not possible to have one single query returning a differenent set of columns. You can a) use dynamic SQL or b) call different queries according to a parameter (e.g. with a stored procedure).

Comment: So depending on the value of Second_Table.X you want to have 2 or 3 columns returned? If that is right I don't see any way to do that without a series of If Then Else conditions. Have you considered dynamic SQL?

Comment: Please post sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert statements), your current attempt and desired results.

Comment: @Isaac It does look like Dynamic sql is the only 'elegant' way of doing this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic sql is the best way to resolve this as suggested in the comments.